# If all zoo animals were set free, which ones could adapt

Tags: internal-consistency, fauna, post-apocalypse

In this scenario, all the humans on earth have disappeared, except for Fred. Sure, Fred is sad that everyone that exists is dead but him, including his friends and family, but he doesn't let that get him down in the dumps. What did get the former PETA supporter, Fred, sad was all the zoo critters. So he hopped in his car and trucked across America to free the zoo animals. Foolishly though, after freeing them, he was eaten by a lion.

Now that Fred has freed all the zoo animals in America (don't concern yourself with how he did this), did he accomplish anything? Would the animals commonly kept in zoos, such as lions, chimps or hippos even be able to survive in an environment so different from their own?

Comment: I mean some zoos have deer and there's a friggin plague of them in my neighborhood eating my squash, so I'm going with deer.

Comment: North America is a big place. A lion will have a better time of it in, say, Mexico as in Calgary. And zoos keep a lot of animals. I fear this question is too broad. America is an even bigger place. Do you mean the United States (still too big)?

Comment: There's probably a huge variety of animals already out there happily living and breeding in places they shouldn't.  Escobar's Hippos, Pelicans in London's parks, wallabies in the UK.  Obviously pack/herd animals would cope better with freedom than lone predators.  Well, predators would be able to eat, but probably won't find mates.

Comment: @Pete, most of the big predators are kept in mating pairs/groups in the hope that they will. At least at respectable zoos

Comment: @Separatrix - Lions maybe, as they're pride animals.  Leopards, Cheetahs etc. tend to hunt alone, and seek mates when they get broody (and don't tolerate each other in non-breeding times).  This requires a certain concentration of suitable mates within an area though.

Comment: Well the Panda bears would definitely die from the lack of bamboo

Comment: I think that few of the zoo animals would escape on their own before starving to death.  Which may be why you have Fred release them.  But Fred should only get to a comparatively few zoos before the animals died.

Comment: [A return of herds of roving, feral camels in the West?](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/whatever-happened-wild-camels-american-west-180956176/) Yes, please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because "America" is an enormous and diverse place spanning pretty much every biome, and because zoos contain dozens and dozens of different animals, I'm going to narrow this down to the Oregon Zoo here in my hometown of Portland, Oregon. Here's [their list of animals](http://www.oregonzoo.org/discover/animals/list) and some information about their habitats.

Since their main threat, humans, are gone, the question of survival is mostly one of habitat, food and predators. The area around Portland has very diverse climate and terrain and it rarely freezes (*he writes while there's snow outside*) which gives the animals a good chance. Portland is also a fairly small city geographically, the zoo is at the edge, and it's surrounded by large amounts of forest, so the animals have a good chance of blundering their way into wilderness. In contrast, animals released from the Bronx Zoo will probably never made it out of the concrete and suburban jungle that is the Northeast Corridor.

On the other hand, for the animals described as "tropical" or "sub-Saharan" or "desert" are probably screwed.

I'm not going through the whole list, just A and B to give you an idea.

## Won't Survive The Winter

- African bullfrog
- African lungfish
- African red-billed hornbill
- African rock python
- African slender-snouted crocodile
- African spurred tortoise
- Allen's swamp monkey
- Arrau turtle
- Black crake
- Black rhinoceros
- Blue and gold macaw
- Blue-streaked lory
- Burmese python

## Might Be OK

- African crested porcupine
- African pygmy hedgehog
- African wild dog
- Asian elephant
- Australian walking stick
- Black howler monkey
- Bontebok
- Bull trout (the Willamette River is probably too polluted)

## Just Fine

- American beaver
- American black bear
- Amur leopard
- Amur tiger
- Bald eagle
- Bobcat
- Bufflehead

Comment: The Blue and Gold Macaws might be okay, there are several instance of escaped wild parrots becoming feral populations in places you might not expect. London has a population of feral parakeets.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingston_parakeets. In this scenario of course humans will be gone so perhaps there is less feeding opportunities.

Comment: Black Rhinos won't survive the winter? You live in Portland, man, not Chicago.

Comment: @kingledion Portland is well outside a rhino's natural range. [Black rhinos range from equatorial Africa to South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_rhinoceros#Distribution). [Cape Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Town) is a full 10 degrees of latitude closer to the equator than Portland and is 5C warmer in winter. It's snowing right now.

Comment: I thought (prehistoric) humans were a contender for the extinction of the native rhinos.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Yes, we are, probably plus desertification of North Africa. But they've never ranged outside the tropical zone. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinoceros#/media/File:Rhinocerotidae_distribution_map.png. The solid colors are the rhino's current range and the outlines are its historical ones.

Comment: There were cold climate rhinos but they are noticeably different than modern rhinos. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woolly_rhinoceros And did not live in NA.

Answer (score 1):

So you start off with all over the world and then switch to America both of which have vast and varying different environments within them as other posters said.

What we can assume is that tropical species will only really survive in the South East with the most success being Florida, as the hundreds if not thousands of invasive flora and fauna show many exotics would have no issue here. Also Hawaii which is already afflicted similarly by many invasive species could also support many new ones from the zoos.

Mediterranean and Desert species will obviously stand their best chances in the US Southwest, possibly certain Savannah Species even, if lucky perhaps lions which once ranged in Antiquity in the Balkans and Greece and more recently lived in Morocco where temperatures can get colder in winter could become established enough in California with its similar climate.

Temperate species from Europe and North East Asia would likely carve out different ranges throughout much of the US bar the Deep South and Deserts.

Arctic and tundra species would do fine in Alaska where many of them are already found.

Here's some species I think are most likely/most interesting:

- Certain penguin species from Africa, Oceania and South America which are released near enough to the coasts will likely form colonies, often zoos have pretty large colonies already which would be a good foundation stock, they would as everywhere be predated by sharks and orcas.
- Tigers would likely gain a footing somewhere but would likely be regionally isolated, there are more tigers in captivity in the US than in the wild globally so any zoos with multiple genetically distant enough specimens would  form the foundations of North American tiger populations. Tiger subspecies are found in numerous different environments they specialise to, the Tigers in the US would be of mixed descent so there would be some selection pressures for whatever genes are best for specific environments. They would not be found in the Deserts and  due to their mixed descent unless there are dominant genes from Siberian/Amur Tigers places with harsh winters likely would not have these Tigers.
- Some species of kangaroos and wallabies would establish due to their wide ranges in Australia and them being found in temperate, Mediterranean, desert and tropical environments.
- Temperate suited primates, although rare there are a few species that could do well in North America. The most likely being the Barbary Macaque which can survive in snow and is naturally found even in oak and pine forests and has a wide range of habitat in its native lands. Ironically this monkey would probably fair worst in the subtropics and tropics. Then more unlikely but interesting is Mountain Gorillas could likely survive in the more mild portions of the Pacific Northwest that resemble their native Montane Forests, these gorillas occasionally go high up into the tundra of the high mountains in East Africa so are cold hardy but are not used to seasonal changes so scarcity of suitable food in winter may be more of an issue.
- Capybaras. The world's largest rodent is a favourite of zoo goers the world over and is very social so usually kept in large groups, they are found as far South as Northern Argentina were it's subtropical and it can get cooler in the winter and are semiaquatic herbivores by nature so these guys would survive anywhere with mild or warmer winters and ample wetland habitat. They would probably be most prolific in the deep south bit possibly around rivers on the West Coast and possibly in Hawaii also. They would become a common prey item of Alligators and Pumas.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking small animals have a higher chance of survival than big ones because they need less food to go through winter.

A lion needs to eat every week. I m not sure how they would catch prey every week in a cold winter.

Animals whose habitats are extremely different from America (polar bears, african giraffe) will probably struggle.

Then there is the question of reproduction. Even if your 4 african leopards can survive America's climate, if they don't stick together all the time (they don't), the chances of them meeting another leopard are quite low. Thus they would go extinct.

Comment: Insects and small animals that can breed in huge numbers would be the biggest contenders. Some zoos keep a population of feeder animals those might be the biggest concern.

Comment: African animals, particularly South African ones, might do just fine in the warm and semi-arid parts of the US Southwest, assuming they could eat what's there. Whereas polar bears might do fine in Maine which isn't too far from their natural habitat of Newfoundland. This is the problem with asking about "America" (by which I think the OP means the United States) because it's such a large area with a diverse series of biomes.